# Amazon AWS - How to copy and replace instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Pretty new with Amazon AWS. I've inherited the setup from another dev, and I've never used AWS before. Need some help with copy and replacing instances. Pretty much there's a dev and a production instance. I need to backup the dev instance and then replace the dev instance with the current production instance.

What I've done so far:
Created Image of test instance. SO it's currently under AMIs.

What I need:

Instructions on how to replace the current dev instance with the production one.

Additional Info:

Both instances have different Public DNS and Public IP.

Anyone got any quick instructions on how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'quick' instructions are to simply create an AMI of the production image (shut it down first), then you use that saved AMI as the basis for creating a new instance. You'll end up with 3 instance, and you can delete your old dev instance once you confirm the new copy of production came up as you wanted - you don't actually 'replace' the dev instance, (you create new and delete the old).

Lots of links to be found for this, but here is one:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSToolkitVS/latest/UserGuide/tkv-create-ami-from-instance.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Got it working. Quick question, you said to shut down production image before creating instance. is it always better to shut down before creating?

Comment: Yes, its always better, but not required - just, imo, the safer way; not always feasible though.

Comment: The new devsite created from the prodcution site instance has all of the config settings from the production site. Is there an actual place where I can go to download the previous devsite instance I created? To check the old devsite config files? The issue now is that I went to RDS and there's only 1 database in there and it's for the production, so not sure what config the devsite was using.

Comment: Unless you deleted it, you should still be able to access it just fine; you can't 'download' it that I know of, but should still be able to connect to it - though I am confused now because you asked about EC2, but now you are talking about RDS - they are not the same thing.

Comment: yea, I'm pretty confused myself. I guess I'm just used to using cPanel. What's in my mind now is that RDS is where the website's database is located. And EC2 is like a filemanager? I see an instance of the production databse in RDS, not for the devsite. I didn't delete the test instance; what would be the correct way to access it? I just need to check the config file settings on test.

Comment: ec2 is a server, a virtual server, if its running windows you would/could use RDP (remote desktop) into it. If its Unix, you need to use the equivalent tool (ssh?)

Comment: RDS is remote desktop? But it has DB instances in there. And confirmed that production site is using the DB instance that's in RDS. Any idea?